# Group By date SQL Query on a fact table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this fact table here, I would like using this table to list group by year and have the total number of patients that have PatientType_id = 1101.

Example:

```
2012  5
2012  8
```

The Date_DateKey is actually the date 2012-03-14. I've managed to list the total patients with typeID 1101 for a single year, but I don't know how is possible to list all the years. Could you give me some hints please?

[image][image]

And here's the Date dimension

Comment: What is the data type of the date key?

Comment: If DateKey is a date, you should use something like DatePart. If not, you should treat the field as a string and extract the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, a key column in a fact table would reference another table.  So, you should have a date/calendar table somewhere with information like the year.  That would be the proper way to get this information.

I discourage you from parsing key values in general.  In this case, with the information you have provided, it seems to be the only solution:

```
select floor(date_datekey / 10000) as year, count(distinct patient_id)
from table t
where PatientType_id = 1101
group by floor(date_datekey / 10000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're rigth, Sorry this is my Date table http://grab.by/CYvM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(DateKe,4) as Year, COUNT(patient_id) FROM Table WHERE  PatientType_id = 1101 GROUP BY LEFT(DateKe,4)
```